# Integrating $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^5+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d}}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, elliptic-curves, elliptic-integrals, quintics

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^5+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d}}$$

I know we have $E,K,$ and $\Pi$ to integrate quartics under the radical, but I wonder what functions quintics yield? Are there any known?

Comment: Are you missing a $x^4$ term?

Comment: Integrals like these are often called “hyper-elliptic”: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Hyper-elliptic_integral

Comment: @user170231 That can be achieved afterwards by translating $x$.